# Сетевой маршрут через промежуточный хост

Tags: linux, сеть, маршрутизация

Думаю вопрос популярный, но ответа найти не могу.
[image: схема сети]

Есть 3 виртуальных линукс-машины. К A и B у меня есть рутовый доступ.
Нужно проложить маршрут из A к C (tcp, udp соединения).

Как можно такое провернуть? Желательно, чтобы А соединялся с C по его родному IP. Проброс портов на B делать не хочу. т.к на C куча сервисов (SSH, SNMPT, HTTP и т.д.), и тоже самое есть на машине B.

Comment: По родному IP соединение пойдет через Интернет. А так - как вообще ходят пакеты от B до С?

Comment: Насколько я знаю B и C находятся в одном датацентре и там всё ок. Что из C пингуется B, что и из B -> C.

Comment: Вся проблема насколько я понимаю это в разных интерфейсах на B. нужно как-то перенаправить пакеты на B из eth0 в eth1. Я в сетевом администрировании слаб, поэтому не уверен возможно ли создать такой мост.

Comment: @АнтонЛакотко, я правильно понял, что хост *b* доступен с хоста *a* по адресу 10.120.30.200? или по адресу 2.5.60.200?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да все верно. интерфейс eth0

Comment: ну, тогда на машине *a* добавьте маршрут к *c*: `$ sudo ip r a 60.1.200.1 via 10.120.30.200 dev tun0` (я так понимаю, что ip-адрес 10.120.30.200 доступен именно через интерфейс `tun0`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin секунду. сейчас попробую. А так да. ВПН-ка создает tun0 интерфейс и автоматом прописывает роут к 10.120.30.200

Comment: да, конечно, ещё: на машине *b* должен быть разрешён форвардинг пакетов. ну и snat на ней наверняка понадобится.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну вот. видимо не разрешен, т.к. пинги вроде есть, но опять же не совсем понятно пингуется тот ли хост. т.к. вроде IP C хоста есть в интернете. Можешь подсказать как разрешить "правильный" форвардинг через iptables? т.к. там для меня слишком сложный ман :)

Answer (score 1):

**обновление**

нижеизложенное подходит лишь для описанной автором ситуации.

на самом же деле ситуацию у автора сложнее — до машины *b* нет **прямого** маршрута, только через *default gateway*.

---

**ответ, подходящий для первоначально изложенной ситуации**

1. на машине *b* надо разрешить «форвардинг» пакетов:

   ```
   $ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
2. на машине *b* надо преобразовывать поле «адрес отправителя» для пакетов, приходящих от машины *a* и уходящих через интерфейс *eth1* (по одному правилу для *tcp* и *udp*):

   ```
   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 172.20.200.141 -o eht1 -j SNAT --to-source 2.5.60.200
   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s 172.20.200.141 -o eht1 -j SNAT --to-source 2.5.60.200
   ```
3. на машине *a* надо «проложить» маршрут до машины *c* через *b*:

   ```
   $ sudo ip r a 60.1.200.1 via 10.120.30.200 dev tun0
   ```

Comment: Ок, сейчас проверю. спасибо

Comment: подразумевается, что машина *b* «видит» машину *a* по адресу 172.20.200.141.

Comment: я добавил про *udp*.

Comment: да, столкнулся с проблемой что из B не видно A.

Comment: сейчас попробую на другую машину вместо А, там все видно

Comment: Ошибки. 1-я была из-за того что  у меня не было таблицы POSTROUTING, создал через iptables -N POSTROUTING
Затем следующее:
`iptables: Invalid argument. Run dmesg for more information.`

`[94957.365952] x_tables: ip_tables: SNAT target: only valid in nat table, not filter`

Comment: да, *-t nat* — я пропустил при копировании. создавать цепочку *postrouting* в таблице *filter* — не надо. лучше удалите её. я внёс поправку в ответ.

Comment: Еще одна проблема при выполнении ip: `RTNETLINK answers: No such process`
Гугл говорит, что это может значить, что 10.120.30.200 не известный хост.
На прошлой A машине, команда прошла хорошо. 10.120.30.200 -- пингуется хорошо.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26547/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and--).